# markdownでローカルに保存した画像を添付する方法がわかりません。

Tags: markdown

画像を添付する表記方法として
    `![alt用テキスト](画像URL)`
となっているようですがローカルに保存した画像を上記の表記方に沿って添付しようとすると代替テキストが表示されるだけとなってしまいます。

どなたか、アドバイスして頂けたら幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown は元々 HTML に変換されることを意図して作られたマークアップ言語ですので、HTML 同様、ローカルファイルへの URI を書いてやることでリンクは可能です（たとえば相対パスを直接書いたり、 `file:///path/to/file` を使ったり）。

ただし、整形後の Markdown を表示する際どのように表示しているかによって、ローカルの画像がどのように扱われるかが処理系依存になります。たとえば Markdown を HTML に変換してブラウザで閲覧する場合、セキュリティへの懸念のため、ローカルファイルへの URI は開かれない設定になっていることが[多いです](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32575280/5989200)。エディタの簡易表示プラグインを使って表示している場合も同様の問題があります。

このため、ご自身の環境のみにおいて表示するワークアラウンドは上述の通りあるかもしれませんが、万人が同様に表示できるような方法は（あったとしても）採用しないことが望ましいでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

[`data:` URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) を使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。
画像ファイルから `data:` URLを作成するのは 自分で base64 エンコードしてもいいですしジェネレータもいくつもあります。（例 http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker ）
これでできた `data:image/` なんたら という文字列を `![代替テキスト](data:image/…)` のように通常の http(s) URLの代わりに入れます。

Visual Studio Code 1.21 でプレビュー表示できました。

ただし

- ブラウザによっては大きい画像は表示できない。
- 文書としてはメンテナンスしづらい大変なものになる。受け取った人がここの画像をちょっと修正して差し替えようとか困難になる。

といった問題はあります。

Answer (score 0):

`file:///path/to/image.jpg`のように、`http://`の代わりに`file:///`を指定するとどうでしょうか。

Comment: `http://`の代わりに`file:///`としたところテキストエディタ上(vscode)で画像の添付パスを`ctrl+左クリック`で開けるようにはなりました。しかし、プレビュー表示やhtmlに変換した際はいまだに代替テキストの表示のみとなってしまいます。